# Upgrade Tridion 2013 SP1 to Web 8.5 - DD4T vs DXA

Tags: dxa, dd4t, web8.5, cil

We are going to upgrade one of our SDL Tridion implementation from 2013 SP1 to Web 8.5. We are using DD4T 1.3 with in-process while for the upgrade we are planning to use CIL. We are considering DD4T 2.2 for the upgrade but want to understand if there is any benefit\challenge we are going to have if we use DXA instead of DD4T so that it will be future proof considering merging of DD4T and DXA.

Answer (score 2):

To learn more about the merge and DXA benefits and How it affects you, you can check out the following blog posts:

[DXA 2.0 AND DD4T](http://dd4t.org/dxa2.html) - dd4t.org

[Merging DD4T and DXA](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/merging-dd4t-and-dxa) - Bart Koopman

[DXA 2.0 architecture](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/dxa-2-0-architecture) - Bart Koopman

[How Will the DD4T and SDL DXA Merger Affect You?](http://www.mrgn.co/2016/10/11/how-will-the-dd4t-and-sdl-dxa-merger-effect-you/) - Chris Morgan

[SDL Releases the SDL Digital Experience Accelerator 2.0](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/b/product-announcements/posts/sdl-releases-the-sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-0) - Bart Koopman

[Switching to the DXA 2 Model Service In your DD4T Application](http://blog.trivident.com/switching-to-the-dxa-2-model-service-in-your-dd4t-application/) - Quirijn Slings

SDL Tridion Sites DXA features [Data sheet](https://www.sdl.com/download/data-sheet-sdl-tridion-sites-dxa/111563/)

What’s new in this DXA 2.0 release

SDL Digital Experience Accelerator (DXA) version 2.0 introduces a new architecture and additional features [read more](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v10&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-F3042BAD-A828-4484-AE15-7E02FE4CE2B8&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-F3042BAD-A828-4484-AE15-7E02FE4CE2B8.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-F3042BAD-A828-4484-AE15-7E02FE4CE2B8)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Velu, please add the official announcement from the DD4T community about this topic: http://dd4t.org/dxa2.html

Comment: thanks @velmurugan, is there any detailed documentation of DXA model service as well. All i found is just a high level overview